# How to configure iOS icon for Flutter application?

Tags: flutter, flutter-launcher-icons

I am using [flutter_launcher_icons](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons) to configure icons for my Flutter app.

Overall it works except one thing. iOS shows correct icon on home screen, but still shows standard Flutter icon for running application.

Home screen:

[image: home screen]

Running app:

[image: running appenter code here]

How can I fix it?

My pubspec.yaml:

```
...
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.13.1
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0
  integration_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

flutter_launcher_icons:
  android: true
  ios: true
  remove_alpha_ios: true
  image_path: 'assets/icon/icon.png'
```

Output after running `dart run flutter_launcher_icons`:

```
  ════════════════════════════════════════════
     FLUTTER LAUNCHER ICONS (v0.13.1)                               
  ════════════════════════════════════════════
  
• Creating default icons Android
• Overwriting the default Android launcher icon with a new icon
• Overwriting default iOS launcher icon with new icon
No platform provided

✓ Successfully generated launcher icons
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a simulator delete the app and reinstall and if you are using a real device a device reatart will clear this issue.